# Generating & Plotting Histograms of Gradient Magnitude & Orientation

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

Using `matplotlib` how can I generate & display a histogram of the image gradient magnitude and orientation?

One thing I don't know is the x axis limits; for magnitude should it be 0 to 1? Ie, the strength of an edge is between 0 and 1? For orientation I assume the x axis limits would be 0 to 360 (degrees) or should I do radians?

Below is how I generate my gradient, magnitude and orientation. How can I now show each as a histogram?

```
def get_gradient(src):

    sobelx = cv2.Sobel(src,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)
    sobely = cv2.Sobel(src,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=5)

    grad = sobelx + sobely
    mag = cv2.magnitude(sobelx, sobely)  # so my Mat element values could be anything between 0 and 1???
    ori = cv2.phase(sobelx, sobely, True) # so my Mat element values could be anything between 0 and 360 degrees???
    return [grad, mag, ori]

grad_res = get_gradient(src)

# number of bins is 100 from 0 to 1. Ie, 0.001, 0.002, ... 1.000 
# am I correct?
mag_hist = cv2.calcHist([grad_res[1]],[0],None,[100],[0,1]) 

ori_hist = cv2.calcHist([grad_res[2]],[0],None,[360],[0,360]) 

plt.plot(mag_hist)
plt.xlim([0,1])

plt.plot(ori_hist)
plt.xlim([0,360])

plt.show()
```

**Edit:** Current error from the above code:

> mag_hist = cv2.calcHist([gradient[1]],[0],None,[10],[0,100])
>   error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\histogram.cpp:1422: error: (-210)  in function cv::calcHist

Comment: Also attach the current output and expected output ?

Comment: @ZdaR I've added the error output. The expected output is the plotted histograms.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds thanks I'll look into that. Re my magnitude Mat - what would be the range of values for a gradient magnitude value (0-1 or 0-255, 0-n)? Ie, the output from `cv2.magnitude(sobelx, sobely)`

Comment: @JakeM Sorry, I deleted the comment because they were recreating the bins and drawing them and it didn't answer the question you posted. However, my posted answer should help you out! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning 64-bit floats, which `calcHist` does not support. You need to cast them to 32-bit floats. Either change the type in your `cv2.Sobel()` call to `cv2.CV_32F` or use `[grad_res[1].astype('float32')]` as the argument in `cv2.calcHist()`.

From [OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html):
**images** – Source arrays. They all should have the same depth, `CV_8U` or `CV_32F` , and the same size. Each of them can have an arbitrary number of channels.